# Execute a method with a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the `index.html.erb` page I have a form_for like this :

```
<%= form_for @cv do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit "Verrouiller", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'%>
<% end %>
```

Do you know how I can launch a method defined in the controller when I click on submit?

the method in my controller is define like :

```
def verrou
   #the script here
end
```

Comment: In your index action put     @cv = youmodel.new

Comment: You can. But you then should have a route declared to the method inside the controller. So, if you have it, then on submit, you call the controller action using its corresponding route, using JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `Resource-oriented style`, here is an example from the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for):

```
<%= form_for(@cv, url: verrou_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And as expected, you need to define your route to `verrou` on your `routes.rb`